# Show if a homomorphism has a non trivial kernel

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

[image]

For Q1(a) I have shown, by the property of distribution for matrices, that 1(a) is a homomorphism.

I have tried to show that it only has a non-trivial kernel but cannot find an example. Would I be correct in saying it only has a trivial kernel and how should I show this for the general case?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you need help for the other parts too?

Comment: No I have already found the solution for the other part, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ Use rank nullity theorem to show that $\text {nullity} (A) = m - \text {rank} (A) \geq m-n > 0$ and observe that $ker\ (\phi)$ is the null space of $A.$